# Can't Uncompress JDK7 Zip FIle

Tags: jdk

I'm trying to download and install Java Development Kit 7 onto my Ubuntu machine. I've downloaded the file from Oracle (jdk-7u25-linux-x64.tar.gz) but when I try to uncompress the file using `tar -xvf jdk-7u25-linux-x64.tar.gz` I get the following error:

```
tar: jdk-7u25-linux-x64.tar.gz: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong? If not how do I fix?

Answer (score 1):

Copy the file to a suitable directory like you `Home` Folder and try the command again. Check [this](http://www.wikihow.com/Install-Oracle-Java-on-Ubuntu-Linux) site out for further information!

Answer (score 0):

By default files are downloaded into the `~/Downloads` folder.  So open a terminal, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
ls ~/Downloads/*.tar.gz
```

Untar the file, and install it at /usr/lib/jvm/ directory:

```
sudo mkdir -p /usr/lib/jvm/
sudo tar xvf ~/Downloads/jdk-7u25-linux-x64.tar.gz -C /usr/lib/jvm
```